# Using GDI+ vs HTML page

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc

I am working on an application which is UI intensive (i.e. we need to customize all the control to look different).

For this is I planned to use GDI+ in win32. But one of the suggestion form our team member is,
Instead of using GDI+ he asked me to have a web browser control, in that he asked me to display local html.That html page contains customized controls.

Form his suggestion I created a web control and used some UI intensive local html pages. That looks good.

But my question is, is it is a good idea to use web control to solve this?

Comment: I feel it's not possible to offer a definitive answer from the information provided, but will offer some thoughts. (1) MFC basically limits you to x86 windows machines only. Increasingly, people want to access the same functionality regardless of their device & OS. (2) Not sure what x86 win browsers use for rendering - GDI or GDI+ (gdi is faster), but unless your application needs to update the controls at a rapid rate, it's really not important - 50% more or less of almost nothing is still almost nothing. In closing, HTML sounds likely to be the more flexible solution, but it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

Using a web browser control to solve this problem is common. There are many applications out there that already do this. For example [Steam](http://www.steampowered.com/) uses Chromium instead of the web browser control to do all its window skinning. Windows 8 metro is another example of an HTML-based interface. There are even entire frameworks built on html-based interfaces such as [Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/). There are many benefits to going the web browser control route but it is not easy to get it right.